# Discord.py Slash commands don't work in cogs

Tags: python, discord

I am building a discord bot, and want to use slash commands inside cogs, but the commands don't show or work, here is the code

```py
## cog
guild_ids = [858573429787066368, 861507832934563851]

class Slash(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @cog_ext.cog_slash(name="test", guild_ids=guild_ids, description="test")
    async def _test(self, ctx: SlashContext):
        embed = Embed(title="Embed Test")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


## bot
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{bot.user} has logged in.')
  bot.load_extension('slash_music_cog')

bot.run("bot-token")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After working at this issue for myself for way longer than I'd like to admit, I've finally found the culprit:
You have to load your cogs **before** running the bot.
For some reason, it won't register your commands with discord, if you load the cogs in the `on_ready` function, so the solution here, is to move your extension-loading code to right before your `bot.run("bot-token")` statement.

So the finished code should look something like

```
## cog
guild_ids = [858573429787066368, 861507832934563851]

class Slash(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @cog_ext.cog_slash(name="test", guild_ids=guild_ids, description="test")
    async def _test(self, ctx: SlashContext):
        embed = Embed(title="Embed Test")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


## bot
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{bot.user} has logged in.')


bot.load_extension('slash_music_cog')
bot.run("bot-token")
```

Comment: You can also use `async def setup_hook(self)` which is called before `on_ready` and is a better place to setup cogs:  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=setup%20hook#discord.ext.commands.Bot.setup_hook

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to slightly modify the `bot.py` file to initialize a `SlashCommand` object. Take a look at the library's [README](https://github.com/discord-py-slash-commands/discord-py-interactions) for a slightly more detailed example of a bot using cogs.

```py
# bot
from discord_slash import SlashCommand

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
slash = SlashCommand(bot)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{bot.user} has logged in.')
  bot.load_extension('slash_music_cog')

bot.run("bot-token")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it but it still does not work, it runs without any errors but nothing still shows up

Comment: Not quite sure what's wrong in that case... I'd recommend trying to work from the README's example (make sure you can get it to work, then try and modify the cog).

Answer (score 0):

After much hassle, I've finally found out how to do it. Your main.py/bot.py should look something like this:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('!'), intents=intents)
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)
```

You need to use sync_commands=True, otherwise the commands don't appear or sync, both in the main module and the cogs.